# Phoenix sqlline cannot display all columns of table on terminal

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

Use phoenix sqlline to connect the hbase. On SecureCRT terminal I can only see three columns of table which has more than 10 columns. I would like to display all columns of the table to test if data is ok. Is there any  configuration should be set?

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:10.35.66.72:2181:/hbase> select * from WL.MSGCENTER_PUSHMESSAGE;
+--------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    PLANID    | BATCHID |                                                                                                                                                 |
+--------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 520          | 1       | C285995F-AB23-4CF0-A9A4-F29175E9CD36                                                                                                           |
+--------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

1 row selected (0.805 seconds)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can change the output format from horizontal to vertical

```
!outputformat vertical
```

Comment: Agreed, this is very useful and should be the accepted answer. It serializes the table, which is often what a JSON API would do.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the terminal width before starting sqlline

```
stty cols 200
```

Answer (score 1):

Sqlline is not smart enough to adjust column width. Make the terminal wider and you might see the data.
Ideally, i would recommend you to `use squirrel-sql or db-visualizer` to connect to Phoenix. They are much better tool to query Phoenix.

Have a look at this: http://search-hadoop.com/m/9UY0h2sGBoSz1Mta1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Jupyter to connect HBase.

Our team use this approach and I can easily view all the columns with a horizontal scroll in Juypter.

Here's the code snippet I use:

```python
import phoenixdb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)


def hb_query(x):
    conn = phoenixdb.connect(url='http://xxxxx:1234')
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(x)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        des = cursor.description
    conn.close()
    columns = [i.name.lower() for i in des]
    df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    
    return df_tmp

df = hb_query("""
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_ABCD
""")

df    #view rows here
```

FYI, you might need to set up Jupyter first which I don't know how and whether it's difficult to set up. My leader set up the environment long before.